# Overlay Static Images on R Leaflet htmlwidget

Tags: html, r, leaflet, htmlwidgets

It it possible to overlay an image to R leaflet maps - or perhaps in the leaflet html - that would stay fixed overtop the map itself?

That is, the image wouldn't be rendered on the map itself, but fixed in the viewport of the browser, so that when you pan or zoom, it would stay the same size in the same position.

For example, I would want to overlay [this image](https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.svg), fixed to the top-left of a map rendered with the following R code:

```
library(htmlwidgets)
library(leaflet)

m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")

saveWidget(m, file = "m.html", selfcontained = F)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `addLogo()` from package **mapview**.

```
library(htmlwidgets)
library(leaflet)
library(mapview)

img <- "https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.svg"

m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R") %>%
  addLogo(img, url = "https://www.r-project.org/logo/")

m
```

Answer (score 1):

In the html, you can add a  with a high z-index - which places the  inside above the htmlwidget.

For the example above, including the following html above the htmlwidget container overlays the image.

```
<div style="position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:11000;">
<img src="https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.svg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a leaflet question but I wanted to see if it worked with googelway and `add_overlay()` - and it does:

```
library(googleway)

map_key <- 'my_map_key'

google_map(key = map_key ) %>%
    add_overlay(north = -36.852, east = 174.768, west = 174.668, south = -36.952,
            overlay_url = "https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.svg")
```

[image]